# How to describe the datastore of system in document if using ORM technology

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

Normally using the traditional Relational database, I would draw a ERD and write field discretion.

When using ORM technology, what is the different in documentation?

How can i describe the data model in document?

Comment: Consider ORM the access layer to your relational database.

Comment: Do the description of your domain model (using class diagram). The translation into database schema depends on the OR mapping and could change (one can modify some mapping attribute and this will lead into different DB schema). If you still want to have ERD, make it from the result tables (automatically) but keep in mind that it is volatile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse engineer your domain model (Entities) and generate EAR diagram or class diagram using different type of plugins.

Have a look here where you can see what [free uml diagrams there are for Java/Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse)